# Ruby on Rails on ubuntu 13.04 using rvm

Tags: ruby, localhost, rails, rvm

I am trying to get WEBrick to work

Output of `rvm gemset list`

```
gemsets for ruby-1.8.7-p374 (found in /home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374)
   (default)
   global
=> simple_cms
```

my gem list
    gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.0)
actionpack (3.0.0)
activemodel (3.0.0)
activerecord (3.0.0)
activeresource (3.0.0)
activesupport (3.0.0)
arel (1.0.1)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.0)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
erubis (2.6.6)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
i18n (0.4.2)
mail (2.2.20)
mime-types (1.25.1)
mysql2 (0.3.15)
polyglot (0.3.4)
rack (1.2.8)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.0)
railties (3.0.0)
rake (10.1.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.38)
```

and when I run the `rails s` to start WEBrick, I got

```
/home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:74:in `setup': undefined method `rubygems' for Bundler:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:114:in `check'
    from /home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:121
    from /home/simon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:118:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/simon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:118:in `require'
    from /home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4
    from /home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `call'
    from /home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `run'
    from /home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    from /home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
    from /home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@simple_cms/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use Rails 3.0.0

**Solution**

delete old gemset

```
rvm gemset delete <gemset-name>
```

create a new gemset  and use it

```
rvm gemset create <gemset-name>
rvm gemset use <gemset-name>
```

You can install the newest verson of rails. On 5 of march 2014, it is 4.0.3 .

If you want to stay with version 3, you need to install newest version of it which is **3.2.17**. do this by running this command

```
gem install rails -v=3.2.17
```